# ASP.net 2.0.50727 doesn't compile or process any .aspx pages

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, iis-7, http-status-code-404

I've created a very simple test scenario - a nice new empty web site without even a web.config.  It returns 404 pages for my test .aspx page when I set the website to use ASP.NET 2.0.50727, but the page processes fine with ASP.NET 1.1.4322.  Any plain .html pages are found and returned to the browser correctly.  The sample page is very simple:

```
<html><head><title>Hello</title></head><body><%= "Hello" %></body></html>
```

I've got other real applications that originally showed the same signs of trouble (404 pages for the entire site) and I've tried doing remote debugging on this server, but it seems to never even load the application assemblies.  I have so far tried rebooting, reinstalling IIS (which creates a new app pool and web site config), reinstalling .net 2.0.x and 3.5, and changing the app pool identity to Local System.

Also, nothing shows up in Windows Event Viewer (except that when I switch from 1.1 to 2.0, it shows "Restarting W3SVC").

I'm at a loss.  How can I troubleshoot IIS itself?  Can I enable some sort of IIS or ASP.NET logging to see what the problem might be?

Some other details:

- Windows 2003 Server
- IIS 7
- ASP.NET 2.0.50727, 3.0, 3.5 installed

Comment: On your server details do you mean IIS 6? 
Win 2003 Server has IIS 6, Win 2008 (or Vista) has IIS 7 [How to download IIS](http://blogs.iis.net/davcox/archive/2009/06/29/how-to-download-iis.aspx)

Comment: How are you switching from 1.0 to 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would firstly check that the application pool is configured to use .NET Framework 2.0. If that is the case and it is not working, I would try running the ASP.NET IIS Registration tool to reinstall the ASP.NET IIS ISAPI bindings:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

Comment: This fixed my simple test case. And it also fixed one of the actual apps running on this server! However, one app is still doing the same thing, showing the 404 page very quickly. I'm going to see if I can use this aspnet_regiis.exe on a single site, or manually try adding the ISAPI binding to the site in question. If you have other suggestions, let me know. Many thanks!

Comment: Update: After getting the first 2 sites working again (specifically using the aspnet_regiis.exe call described above) I was able to get the last few sites working by deleting the IIS website entry and re-creating it. Seems something ate all my configuration, and these couple steps got me back up and running. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS 7, have you configured the site to run in ASP.NET 2.0 with Classic Pipeline Mode?